# C++ global operator method

Tags: c++, c++11

I am not able to understand why I cannot be able to create global operator () method as like:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    public:
        bool operator()(const A& a)
       {
           return true;
       }
};

bool operator()(int a, int b)
{
    return true;
}

int main ()
{
std::cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

When I compile the code I get below error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 a.cpp
a.cpp:11:29: error: 'bool operator()(int, int)' must be a nonstatic member function
 bool operator()(int a, int b)
                             ^
```

If I change the operator to any like + or - I still get the same error? Why we cannot defined global operator method?

Comment: Why do you want a global function-call operator? How would it be used?

Comment: The error says it all `must be a non static member function`

Comment: Because the standard says so. There is no other answer. And it would be pointless anyways.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `::(3, 4)`, I guess?

Comment: `::(3, 4)` .. what will this do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your question has two answer.

When you are writing `operator()(xxx)` you're trying to declare a function call operator. This means that you want to be able to use something as a function. For this to be possible, you have to be able to create an instance of this something, thus it need to be in a class.

As for your question about replacing it by + or -, you could do this, just not in this case. c-like primitives are a special case in c++, and the function `operator xxx(...)` is not called. However, if your replace one of the argument by a class or a struct, then a function will be called, allowing you to overload it (well in this case it's more shadowing than overloading I'd guess).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool operator+(std::string a, int b)
{
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string test;

    std::cout << (test + 10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet does compile and print "1" when executed.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that your overload of `operator+` doesn't follow the "normal" semantics of additions operators. It's highly discouraged to change semantics of common operators, so they don't work in expected ways.

Answer (score 1):

The standard requires few operators that must be member functions, if overloaded (`= () [] ->`). The call operator `()` is one of them.
The error generated by the compiler is telling the same.

I believe this is because of semantics (it's meant to be associated with an object) and "the standard decided so". Why add more complexity by having `::()` global function and disturb it's semantics, when you can just name it something like `Call()`?